# how Garbage collector works under the hood to collect dead object?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was reading up on garbage collection. As we know, Garbage collection collects dead object and reclaims memory. 
My question is, how Collector comes to know that any object is dead? 
what data-structure it use to keep track of live objects?

I was researching about this, I found, GC actually keep track of live objects, and marked them. every object that is not marked consider as dead. I guess, there is some thing called `object-tree` is used for this purpose. but how its works I don't know.

Here are my list of questions.

- what is object-tree?
- how its works? when we create any object with `new` keyword, how it affects  that `object-tree`?
- who maintains this tree? jvm, GC, or that's how objects get stored in heap?

Comment: It walks around the memory, yelling "bring out yer dead!"

Comment: "I'm not out of scope yet!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree is just a conceptual view on the memory heap and the references between objects. It does not exist as a separate entity.

And it's not really a tree since it can contain cycles, so calling it a graph would be more accurate. During garbage-collection it is visited in a tree-like manner (breadth-first or depth-first traversal) by following references and skipping those already visited.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection

Answer (score 1):

Actually Garbage collection I believe works to opposite way to your understanding. It isn't that we collect and track what is dead, we track and collect live objects and everything else designated garbage.

Every item that the developer uses is treated this way, including class objects, static variables, and even the code itself. As long as an object is being referenced, the JVM considers it alive. Once an object is no longer referenced and therefore is not reachable by the application code it is no longer tracked by the JVM and considered garbage.

An object tree is a tree data structure holding objects at the nodes.

The object tree works like this:

1. They must have one or more root objects.
2. Once all of these root objects are reachable, the entire tree is reachable.
3. If the roots are no longer reachable they are deemed garbage

[image: object tree]

I believe it is managed and maintained by the JVM.

[source](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works.html)

Comment: Put the [source](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works.html) at least ;)

Comment: These will have elaborated explanation 
http://www.dynatrace.com/en/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works.html
http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html